# Mixing expression-bodied with throw for multiple parameters

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

May be this might an easy one. But I couldn't work this out if possible.

Because we can apply expression-bodied members to constructors and because throw expressions are available to expression-bodied members, we can simplify following code

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string ProA { get; set; }
    public Foo(string proa)
    {
        if (proa == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value");
        }
        ProA = proa;
    }
}
```

above code can be simplified to:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string ProA { get; set; }
    public Foo(string proa) => ProA = proa ?? 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value");
}
```

**Question:** In my case, I have more than one parameter (in a parameterised constructor ) to parse while construction and would be very helpful if someone can help me to simplify following code with the help of expression-bodied members to constructors along with throwing expressions in case of null

```cs
public class Bar
{
    public string ProA { get; set; }
    public string ProB { get; set; }
    public Bar(string proa, string prob)
    {
        if (proa == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value");
        else if (prob == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid prob value");

        ProA = proa;
        ProB = prob;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the last `else` statement, since all the other cases throw an exception. Also, it's typical that the first invalid argument is the cause for the throwing of an exception, so you could remove the first `if` statement as well.

Comment: @RufusL, You are right I could further simplify the code. However, the idea was to demonstrate current code base. Anyway redundant else is removed. Thanks

Comment: Also, I don't believe you can use `nameof` like that -  it takes a variable, type, or member; not a string.

Comment: @RufusL, Thanks for spotting that out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question:** In my case, I have more than one parameter (in a parameterised constructor ) to parse while construction and would be very helpful if someone can help me to simplify following code with the help of expression-bodied members to constructors along with throwing expressions in case of null

Expression-bodied members was expanded in **C# 7.0** which now includes using them with constructors. The method consists of a *single expression that returns a value whose type matches the method's return type, or, for methods that return void, that performs some operation*.

Let's take a look at your first simplified code block...

```
public class Foo
{
    public string ProA { get; set; }
    public Foo(string proa) => ProA = proa ?? 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value");
}
```

Using the expression-body here is just fine and consist of only `one expression`, so it's valid.

```
public Foo(string proa) => ProA = proa ?? 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value");
```

The problem arises when you have more than one parameter, multiple to deal with and instead of having body declarations, expression bodies should come in handy and work and they do.

Here's *one way to do this* while making it valid.

```
public Bar(string proa, string prob) => 
            (ProA, ProB) = (proa ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value"),
            prob ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid prob value"));
```

Essentially what I am doing here is creating a [ValueTuple Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8) as well as [deconstructing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) which lets you unpackage all the items in a tuple in just a single operation.

Another option you *could* possible do, but more work is call a routine in the class to setup the class when constructed. Going this route though would prove to be a hassle than just handling the changes in a regular body.

References:

[Expression-bodied Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

Comment: Much appreciate your time. I agree the ValueTuple and its deconstruction work as an alternative approach to solve my issue. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: I may be the only one who doesn't have a sweet tooth for all the syntactic sugar, but I find the last code block in the OP's question to be the most readable (this is not a criticism of this answer at all - it addresses exactly what was asked).

Answer (score 1):

> [it] would be very helpful if someone can help me to simplify following code with the help of expression-bodied members to constructors along with throwing expressions in case of null

"Simplify" is often in the eye of the beholder, and I think that's especially true here. I also think you are conflating two different concepts: `throw` in expressions, and lambda-expression method implementations.

If we focus just on the former, your constructor can be simplified considerably (in my view) just by changing the expressions and removing the explicit `if` statements:

```cs
public class Bar
{
    public string ProA { get; set; }
    public string ProB { get; set; }
    public Bar(string proa, string prob)
    {
        ProA = proa ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value");
        ProB = prob ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid prob value");
    }
}
```

It's important to note that there is a subtle change in the flow of the logic. I.e. the parameter validation is done only as each property is assigned, rather than prior to any property assignment. But certainly in a class like this, that's completely inconsequential.

It is possible to do something similar with the lambda-expression method approach, with the same caveat (i.e. that assignment and validation become mingled):

```cs
public class Bar
{
    public string ProA { get; set; }
    public string ProB { get; set; }
    public Bar(string proa, string prob) : this(prob) => ProA = proa ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid proa value");
    private Bar(string prob) => ProB = prob ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Invalid prob value");
}
```

In other words, add a new constructor for each parameter you want to assign, giving that constructor a single lambda expression to assign that parameter, and having the constructor delegate assignment of the remaining parameters to the next constructor (with more parameters/properties, you can see that the parameter list gets one parameter shorter with each call).

I don't personally find this a real improvement. Yes, the code's more compact. But I'm not really sure it's actually more *readable*. And in an important sense, "simple" and "readable" are the same, or at least very closely related.

Comment: I completely agree with your notion of simplicity. As there are more than one overloaded constructors, I can't adopt your proposal on constructor chaining. Also, null coalescing operator is something I already thought about. However, introduction of expression-bodied members to constructors could have been a a little more cleaner approach in my case (personally). Though your proposal doesn't answer my questions, I am definitely up-voting it since it add values to the over all discussion. Much appreciate your time and effort.